# How to pivot a dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have a table in csv format that looks like this.  I would like to transpose the table so that the values in the indicator name column are the new columns,

```
Indicator       Country         Year   Value    
1               Angola          2005    6
2               Angola          2005    13
3               Angola          2005    10
4               Angola          2005    11
5               Angola          2005    5
1               Angola          2006    3
2               Angola          2006    2
3               Angola          2006    7
4               Angola          2006    3
5               Angola          2006    6
```

I would like the end result to like like this:

```
Country    Year     1     2     3     4     5
Angola     2005     6     13    10    11    5
Angola     2006     3     2     7     3     6
```

I have tried using a pandas data frame with not much success.

```
print(df.pivot(columns = 'Country', 'Year', 'Indicator', values = 'Value'))
```

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: @alfasin He could be showing us the tabular data. Regardless I'm *guessing* that if he's using a pandas dataframe that he must already have it parsed as a table somewhere.

Comment: What does your dataframe look like currently? What does it do when you call `pivot` on it, that you're calling "not much success?"

Comment: I've provided several detailed examples and alternative approaches in this  [**Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47152691/2336654) that you or others might find helpful.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can use `pivot_table`:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values = 'Value', index=['Country','Year'], columns = 'Indicator').reset_index()
```

this outputs:

```
 Indicator  Country     Year    1   2   3   4   5
 0          Angola      2005    6   13  10  11  5
 1          Angola      2006    3   2   7   3   6
```

Comment: Looking at the very first line (column names) of the output - why is there an indicator column [left column('`Indicator`')] in addition to  columns derived from the indicators column [right 5 columns (`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`)]?

Comment: It’s the index.

Comment: thanks - I tried doing [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49185446/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe-with-pandas) but had no luck.

Comment: @JAB if the 'Indicator column on the left is the index, why is it still there after doing a `reset_index`?

Comment: @thegreatcoder `reset_index()` flattens the result and you probably need to add `df_your_result_table_name.columns.name = None` to remove it

Answer (score 9):

This is a guess: it's not a ".csv" file, but a Pandas DataFrame imported from a '.csv'.

To pivot this table you want three arguments in your Pandas "pivot". e.g., if 
`df` is your dataframe:

```
table = df.pivot(index='Country',columns='Year',values='Value')  
print (table)
```

This should *should* give the desired output.