# How to pivot a dataframe with pandas so variable columns become rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I currently have the following dataframe:

**Current `df`:**

```
            type       part number    part description  waiting period  hours  
0   service item     SOME-X1R-1807                SOME           1 day     24  
1     CONSUMABLE   RANDOM-462-1171         DESCRIPTION          6 days    144  
2          wheel      PART-7W-2326           ABOUT THE          7 days    168  
3           tyre    NUMBER-1R-0762      PARTS FROM THE          8 days    192  
4          other    NUMBER-XL-0747     PREVIOUS COLUMN          9 days    216
```

I want to pivot the table, and get the following outcome:

**Expected `df`:**

```
                        SOME-X1R-1807    RANDOM-462-1171    PART-7W-2326     NUMBER-1R-076     NUMBER-XL-0747 
part description                 SOME        DESCRIPTION       ABOUT THE    PARTS FROM THE    PREVIOUS COLUMN
            type         service item         CONSUMABLE           wheel              tyre              other
  waiting period                1 day             6 days          7 days            8 days             9 days 
           hours                   24                144             168               192                216
```

**Question:**

How do I pivot a dataframe to get this output?

**Things I have tried:**

- [How to pivot a dataframe in Pandas? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337117/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe-in-pandas/28337349?noredirect=1#comment85376072_28337349)
- [Reshaping and Pivot Tables](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html)
- [Make DataFrame.pivot index argument truly optional](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3962)
- [Reshaping in Pandas - Pivot, Pivot-Table, Stack and Unstack explained with Pictures](http://nikgrozev.com/2015/07/01/reshaping-in-pandas-pivot-pivot-table-stack-and-unstack-explained-with-pictures/)

Comment: Links don't, in themselves, show us your existing code and where it might be failing. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @jpp I was trying `pivot` which is the wrong approach, it should be `set_index`

Comment: *"transform so columns become rows"* = **transpose**

Comment: This should be mentioned as a one-liner in both the pandas doc and SO canonicals you mention.

Comment: In contrast **pivot** keeps the vertical column layout, it just expands/collapses levels of specified variables into new columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think this is pivot

```
df.set_index('part number').T
Out[214]: 
part number         SOME-X1R-1807  RANDOM-462-1171     PART-7W-2326  \
            type     service item       CONSUMABLE            wheel   
part description             SOME       ESCRIPTION        ABOUT THE   
waiting period              1 day           6 days           7 days   
hours                          24              144              168   
part number        NUMBER-1R-0762   NUMBER-XL-0747  
            type             tyre            other  
part description   PARTS FROM THE  PREVIOUS COLUMN  
waiting period             8 days           9 days  
hours                         192              216
```

Comment: What does the `.T` do at the end of the command `df.set_index('part number').T`

Comment: @3kstc *Transpose index and columns* from pandas api :-)