# How to create n new Column based on a categorical variable which holds values of another column in that

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So This is the dataframe.

[image]

the attribute 'age' has 6 discrete values, therefore I want to add 6more columns which holds values from attribute 'suicides_no". and removing 'age' attribute.
So the final DF will look like:

```
Albania 1987  female    0    14    4    6    0     1
Albania 1987   male     0    21    9    16   1     1
```

Note:
Taking suicides_no.values and reshaping it won't help as the total entries are not divisible by 6

Comment: Can you explain how would you like to create these new columns?

Comment: such that the dataframe will be reduced by 1/6 of its total size(rows)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot a dataframe in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337117/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
suicide_df.pivot(index=['country', 'year', 'sex'], columns='age', values='suicides_no').reset_index()
```

Comment: Shukriya. reset_index after that  gave the desired results

Comment: Your'e welcome. Updated my answer to include `reset_index()`.