# Plot through time setting specific filtering

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, group-by

I have a dataset like this:

```
        Freq
Date    
01-11   1
05-11   1
04-10   1
02-12   1
12-10   1
... ...
07-20   286
06-20   288
05-20   390
04-20   471
03-20   510
```

I would like to plot the frequency by month, to create 12 plots one per each month, showing the frequency through through years.
My approach would be: use groupby to group all the months, then plot the histogram of frequency.
But I have encountered a difficulty regarding how to extract months from Date.
I have tried as follows:

```
df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m')).size().sort_values()
```

and then I used plot(kind=bar), trying to apply this once per each month. But the output is different from that expected.

Comment: `Any suggestion on how to..` - Spend some time with the [Pandas User guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html) and the [Matplotlib tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html). ... Search and read lots of Q&A's

Comment: added code to show what I have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, I think want to reshape you dataframe like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,100, 120), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2010',periods=120, freq='MS'))

df = s.reset_index()

df['Year'] = df['index'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['index'].dt.month

ax = df.set_index(['Year', 'month'])[0].unstack('month').plot.bar(subplots=True, layout=(4,3), figsize=(15,10))
plt.suptitle('Values by Months of the Year over Ten-year period');
```

Chart:

[image]
Input dataframe for chart:

```
print(df.set_index(['Year', 'month'])[0].unstack('month'))
```

Years on index and months as columns:

```
month  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
Year                                                 
2010   85  63  68  35   3  77  14  72  78  26  52  61
2011   47  92  37  89  24  62  76  10  88   6  48  77
2012   51   6  27  92  90   6  76  69  45  55   8   7
2013   45  45  53  29  32  13  23  39  82  68  83  41
2014   46   0  53  33  92  62  49  54  39  51  19  20
2015   55  81  95  67  75  93  92  94  67  72  40  26
2016    9  44  36  89  28  92  25  52  80  32  88  37
2017   52  60   0  34   9  72  70  42  88  18  51   3
2018   96  79  83  60  56  12   8  54  57  68   9  69
2019   32  98  47  23  35  28  59  81  86  32  50  52
```

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for answering. I have got this key error: KeyError: 0 when I define ax. Do you know what it does mean?

Comment: Yes, my series has no name therefore, I am using a default column header as 0.  You need to put your actual column header name instead of 0 after the set_index.

Comment: Sorry again. I used both Freq and Date but I have got a ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape. I think I am not understanding. Sorry

Comment: You'll need to use groupby and unstack instead of set_index and unstack.https://stackoverflow.com/q/28337117/6361531

Comment: Thanks @Scott Boston. I think I will need to ask for a new question as, even trying as suggested, I could not find a way to plot this values.