# Python sqlite3: Pivot a Column and create a view based upon the pivoted data

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlite, pivot-table

New to sqlite3 database. Trying to retrieve the data from the table and pivot the data from Column and create a table view based upon that. I looked around and some suggested to use CASE and some suggested to use joins but i am not able to figure out how to write the sql statement to do the pivot on col2 in the table below. Col2 can have n number of rows but need to take only the unique values from col2 and use those unique values to pivot the table. Not sure if this is possible using sqlite3 or should I be doing this outside sqlite3 and use pandas?

Input data is as follows:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 | t1 | Dummy1 | result1 | 10 | 100.2 |
| 2 | test1 | t1 | Dummy2 | result2 | 20 | 101.2 |
| 3 | test1 | t1 | Dummy3 | result3 | 30 | 102.3 |
| 4 | test1 | t1 | Dummy4 | result4 | 40 | 101.4 |
| 5 | test2 | t1 | Dummy1 | result1 | 10 | 101 |
| 6 | test2 | t1 | Dummy2 | result2 | 20 | 103 |
| 7 | test2 | t1 | Dummy3 | result3 | 30 | 104 |
| 8 | test2 | t1 | Dummy4 | result4 | 40 | 105 |
| 9 | test3 | t1 | Dummy1 | result1 | 10 | 102 |
| 10 | test3 | t1 | Dummy2 | result2 | 20 | 106 |
| 11 | test3 | t1 | Dummy3 | result3 | 30 | 107 |
| 12 | test3 | t1 | Dummy5 | result4 | 50 | 110.2 |
| 13 | test4 | t1 | Dummy2 | result2 | 20 | 120 |
| 14 | test5 | t1 | Dummy6 | result1 | 100 | 88 |

Output should look like below:

| col4 | col5 | col6 | test1 | test2 | test3 | test4 | test5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dummy1 | result1 | 10 | 100.2 | 101 | 102 |  |  |
| Dummy6 | result1 | 100 |  |  |  |  | 88 |
| Dummy2 | result2 | 20 | 101.2 | 103 | 106 | 120 |  |
| Dummy3 | result3 | 30 | 102.3 | 104 | 107 |  |  |
| Dummy4 | result4 | 40 | 101.4 | 105 |  |  |  |
| Dummy5 | result4 | 50 |  |  |  |  |  |

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: You can look at [How to pivot a dataframe in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337117/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe-in-pandas) to transform dataframe into pivot table, also what you are trying to do is not possible using SQLite, you should first read the data from the SQLite and then you can use pandas pivot to get the desired behavior.

Comment: Just to highlight some key points: you can't do this in SQL.  You will need to read the data in and process it in code.  `Pandas` is a good choice.