# Transpose values in column to column header?

Tags: python

So I basically need my data to look like the one in the picture below. I've researched endlessly on this site and even created an account to see if anyone can help me.  I'm sorry I don't even know how to properly explain the problem.

[image]

Comment: This is called "pivoting" your data frame. See [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot a dataframe in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337117/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is an incredibly useful library for dealing with data in a tabular format

Assuming you have that data available as either a list of dictionaries, or a dictionary of lists, you can easily create a pandas DataFrame from that data

```
In [31]: data = {'Client': ['Client 1', 'Client 1', 'Client 1', 'Client 2', 'Client 2', 'Client 2', 'Client 3', 'Client 3', 'Client 3'],
    ...:         'Ticker': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    ...:         'PositionValue': [1000, 2000, 10000, 300, 6000, 10000, 45345, 546456, 456456]
    ...:         }

In [32]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [33]: df
Out[33]:
     Client Ticker  PositionValue
0  Client 1      A           1000
1  Client 1      B           2000
2  Client 1      C          10000
3  Client 2      A            300
4  Client 2      B           6000
5  Client 2      C          10000
6  Client 3      A          45345
7  Client 3      B         546456
8  Client 3      C         456456
```

You can then change the shape of that data by pivoting it, [described in the User Guide here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html)

```
In [36]: df.pivot(index = 'Client', columns = 'Ticker', values = 'PositionValue')
Out[36]:
Ticker        A       B       C
Client
Client 1   1000    2000   10000
Client 2    300    6000   10000
Client 3  45345  546456  456456
```