# How to convert pandas series to dataframe with column name from series values?

Tags: python, pandas

This is the series I have:

```
stars  state
1.0    AZ       1348
       NC        371
       NV        754
       OH        345
1.5    AZ       1342
       NC        393
       NV        829
       OH        375
```

I wish to convert this to.

```
state  AZ    NV   NC  OH
starts
1      1348  371 754 345
1.5    1342  393 829 375
```

Comment: Is the data in the `stars` column a list?

Comment: It came from another dataframe ```data.groupby(['stars', 'state'])['stars'].count()```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337117/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe-in-pandas

Comment: How do I specify the value column for ```pivot_table(df, values = 'Value', index=['Country','Year'], columns = 'Indicator').reset_index()```

Comment: @GunJack Can you just show the original dataframe itself then? It'll be easier to work on.