# Reformat Monthly Measurements into Rows for Each Month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame with monthly data points about the climate for about 30 years, and am trying to reformat the DataFrame into a format that another model that will use the data can accept. I am wondering if there is a simple way to reformat a time series data all within a single column into several columns that each represent a month. I'll give example formats below for clarity:

**Current Format:**

| Date | HDD | CDD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-01-01 | 3000 | 0 |
| 2010-02-01 | 2500 | 500 |
| 2010-03-01 | 2000 | 1000 |
| 2010-04-01 | 1500 | 1500 |
| 2010-05-01 | 1000 | 2000 |
| 2010-06-01 | 500 | 2500 |
| 2010-07-01 | 0 | 3000 |
| 2010-08-01 | 500 | 2500 |
| 2010-09-01 | 1000 | 2000 |
| 2010-10-01 | 1500 | 1500 |
| 2010-11-01 | 2000 | 1000 |
| 2010-12-01 | 2500 | 500 |
| 2011-01-01 | 3000 | 0 |
| 2011-02-01 | 2500 | 500 |
| 2011-02-01 | 2000 | 1000 |
| ... | ... | ... |

**Desired Format:**

| Date | Jan-HDD | Jan-CDD | Feb-HDD | Feb-CDD | Mar-HDD | Mar-CDD | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | 3000 | 0 | 2500 | 500 | 2000 | 1000 | ... |
| 2011 | 3000 | 0 | 1500 | 500 | 2000 | 1000 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Let me know if you have any suggestions, thank you!

Below is a code snippet of what I've tried, which leads to errors or a blank DataFrame depending on the parameters passed to the merge function. The code below is just a test, but I was intending to put it in a for loop across each month if it had worked.

```
month = 'January'
ddf = dd[dd['Date'].dt.month_name() == month].rename(columns={'HDD': '{}-HDD'.format(month), 'CDD': '{}-CDD'.format(month)})

month = 'February'
ddf_temp = dd[dd['Date'].dt.month_name() == month]
ddf_temp = ddf_temp.rename(columns={'HDD': '{}-HDD'.format(month), 'CDD': '{}-CDD'.format(month)})
##ddf = ddf.merge(ddf_temp, on='Date', how='outer')
#ddf

pd.merge(ddf, ddf_temp, on='Date')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337117/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe-in-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the last row in your current format table is a typo and should be 2011-03-01.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ("2010-01-01", "3000", "0"),
        ("2010-02-01", "2500", "500"),
        ("2010-03-01", "2000", "1000"),
        ("2010-04-01", "1500", "1500"),
        ("2010-05-01", "1000", "2000"),
        ("2010-06-01", "500", "2500"),
        ("2010-07-01", "0", "3000"),
        ("2010-08-01", "500", "2500"),
        ("2010-09-01", "1000", "2000"),
        ("2010-10-01", "1500", "1500"),
        ("2010-11-01", "2000", "1000"),
        ("2010-12-01", "2500", "500"),
        ("2011-01-01", "3000", "0"),
        ("2011-02-01", "2500", "500"),
        ("2011-03-01", "2000", "1000"),
    ],
    columns=["Date", "HDD", "CDD"],
)
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df = pd.pivot_table(df, values=["HDD", "CDD"], index=df["Date"].dt.year, columns=df["Date"].dt.month)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      CDD                         HDD
Date   1      2       3            1       2       3
2010  0.0  500.0  1000.0  ...  3000.0  2500.0  2000.0  ...
2011  0.0  500.0  1000.0  ...  3000.0  2500.0  2000.0  ...
```